# how do i count tickets with distinct code in a for each

Tags: c#

I am working on creating a pie chart that displays the number of tickets per a month broken down by a distinct code so far i have set my month and year and am able to return the distinct letter code however, counting tickets with that code eludes me. I have so far..

```
var codes = tickets.Select(r => type).Distinct // this is returning as desired //(a,b,c,d)

foreach (string letter in codes) {
// this is where I get confused trying to get the count of tickets that have each code.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `Distinct`, use a `GroupBy` to get the groups and then `Count` to get the count per group:

```
var amountPerCode = tickets
    .GroupBy(x => x.type)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

// will produce: [ { a, 5 }, { b, 1 }, etc ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`tickets.GroupBy(r => type).Select (g => g.Key, g.Count());` is all you need.

Comment: the assignment and the explanation is missing here